# Can I setup my own whatsapp photo, name // use my own phone number in Twilio whatsapp-api? And the sandbox question

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

Now, I am trying to build a program to send notifications to our customers via whatsapp if the product has been updated.

And I have tried using twilio (sandbox), but I am a little confused when using twilio whatsapp api, here is my question ...

1. If I use "Enabled WhatsApp Senders" function, can I use my own phone number or only the twilio phone number (trial number)?
2. If I use "Enabled WhatsApp Senders" function, can I set whatsapp photo and name?
3. After using "Enabled WhatsApp Senders" function, do I need to add all customer numbers to snadbox, or can I use the programming code to send it directly to the customer?
4. After using "Enabled WhatsApp Senders" function, should I always log in to whatsapp? Since I tried other whatsapp-api (must always log in to wahstapp to make the api work ...)

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sW3b.png)

Comment: What is the  "Enabled WhatsApp Senders" function?

Comment: @Alan Sorry for the unclear statement, I have uploaded the relevant pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Twilio number in your account that has been WhatsApp enabled. There is a process you must follow to get a Twilio number WhatsApp enabled, which is defined [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api#enabling-whatsapp-with-a-twilio-number) and [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile) and [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs#setting-up-a-business-profile).

A picture is part of the WhatsApp business profile creation, covered above. Also, pay attention to the behavior difference between a WhatsApp business account and a verified business account for very large brands.

Once your account has its own WhatsApp enabled number, you no longer need to have users subscribe to the shared Sandbox number. You do need to respect the 24hr window for free-form communications and the use of templates for out of session communications, covered in the documentation I shared above, and [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017773294-Rules-and-Best-Practices-for-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio).

There is no need to be logged into WhatsApp. In fact, the Twilio WhatsApp integrations supported [read receipts](https://www.twilio.com/blog/new-rich-features-support-deeper-customer-engagement-twilio-api-whatsapp), so you know when the end-user read your message.